# SCCM 2007 "Local Drive on Site Server" Backup ConfigMgr Site Server Option Greyed Out/Not Available

Tags: sccm, sccm-2007

SCCM 2007 "Backup ConfigMgr Site Server Properties -> Set Paths -> Local Drive on Site Server radio button located in the Destination Options Section is totally greyed out. Is there anyway to get this enabled?

[image: Screen Shot]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found the answer to this. If the site database is not installed on the site server (co-located) this option will be greyed out. My SCCM 2007 site database is on a remote SQL database so that explains it. I found this info in the SCCM 2007 Administrator's Companion.